# How to run drush make on remote using relative path?

Tags: drush

I'm writing a script where I'd like to run .make file, but it fails with the following error:

```
$ drush @remote.test make --no-core profiles/foo/contrib.make --yes
Calling proc_open(ssh drush@remote 'COLUMNS=278 drush  --verbose --yes --root=/var/www  make profiles/foo/contrib.make   --no-core 2>&1' 2>&1);
file_get_contents(profiles/foo/contrib.make): failed to open stream: No such file or directory make.utilities.inc:487
```

despite the file exists. I don't want to hardcode absolute path, as I'd like to use the same command for other remotes.

The command fails, because current directory of drush is set to *HOME* folder, instead of webroot (which is correctly passed internally via `--root`). This example could be related to issue where [drush shell alias is downloading the project into wrong directory.](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/891)

So the question is: **How I can use `drush make` to execute .make file on remote host using relative path?** As it seems to work fine on local.

I'm using drush 7.0-dev on local and remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For workaround, the following command should work:

```
$ drush @remote.test make --no-core $(drush @remote.test dd)/profiles/foo/contrib.make
```

Command `drush dd` will return the webroot path and pass it to outer command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem of running drush from behat and needing to switch to a relative path (docroot) on different environments:

```
drush --root=$(pwd)/docroot [DRUSH COMMAND HERE]
```

where `$(pwd)` **p**rints the **w**orking **d**irectory